# How to use DataFrameIterator and TensorSliceDataset together for training on mixed data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to fit a multi-branched neural network for mixed data inputs on a kaggle notebook for the Melanoma Competition.
I am following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) tutorial in order to make a multi-branched neural net. It is not possible for me to show the network architecture right now because the competition is ongoing. My model shows no error on compilation. However on fitting the model using the following code snippet, the code cell raises a **ValueError**:

```
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=opt)
# train the model
print("[INFO] training model...")
model.fit(
    x=[train_dataset, train_generator],
    epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Here, train_dataset is a BatchDataset object obtained from `from_tensor_slices().shuffle().batch()` method and train_generator is DataFrameIterator obtained from `flow_from_dataframe()` method.

The traceback is shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-2e58e85574a4> in <module>
      5 model.fit(
      6         x=[train_dataset, train_generator],
----> 7     epochs=2, batch_size=32)
      8 # make predictions on the testing data

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    813           workers=workers,
    814           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
--> 815           model=self)
    816 
    817       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model)
   1097     self._insufficient_data = False
   1098 
-> 1099     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1100     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1101         x,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    961         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    962         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 963             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    964   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    965     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>", "<class 'keras_preprocessing.image.dataframe_iterator.DataFrameIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

Can someone help me debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer. There should be a feature request against Keras. They do not support mixed input type of dataset and dataframe iterator. Here is what's in TF 2.2 documentation for model.fit: "Input data. It could be:

```
A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.
A tf.data dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights). A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given below. "
```